# Run through Rspec test multiple times based on argument from array

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, integration-testing, dry, stripe-payments

I'm implementing Stripe and doing integration tests. Stripe provides multiple CC numbers, and I want to iterate through each of these. Something like:

```
    @stripe_success_cards = [
        "4242424242424242", #Visa
        "4012888888881881", #Visa
        "4000056655665556", #Visa debit
        "5555555555554444", #MC
        "5200828282828210", #MC debit
        "378282246310005", #AmEx
        "371449635398431", #AmEx
        "6011111111111117", #Discover
        "6011000990139424", #Discover
        "30569309025904", #Diner's club
        "38520000023237", #Diner's club
        "3530111333300000", #JCB
        "3566002020360505" #JCB
    ]

@stripe_success_cards.each do |card_number|
  describe "user fills out Stripe information"
    before do
      page.execute_script(%Q{ $('input#card_number').val('#{card_number}'); })
    end

    it "should successfully trigger charge" do
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

But the above doesn't work because of the limitations on variables in Rspec integration testing. How can I do this? Just trying to keep the test DRY, because truly each form has a lot to fill out and there are a lot of examples to go through.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe you can use ERB format in that context. You should just interpolate the Ruby variable directly, as in:

`"$('input#card_number').val('#{card_number}');"`

Answer (score 1):

This will work if you use a local variable instead of an instance variable:

```
stripe_success_cards = [
    "4242424242424242", #Visa
    "4012888888881881", #Visa
    "4000056655665556", #Visa debit
    "5555555555554444", #MC
    "5200828282828210", #MC debit
    "378282246310005", #AmEx
    "371449635398431", #AmEx
    "6011111111111117", #Discover
    "6011000990139424", #Discover
    "30569309025904", #Diner's club
    "38520000023237", #Diner's club
    "3530111333300000", #JCB
    "3566002020360505" #JCB
]

stripe_success_cards.each do |card_number|
  describe "user fills out Stripe information"
    before do
      page.execute_script(%Q{ $('input#card_number').val('#{card_number}'); })
    end

    it "should successfully trigger charge" do
      ...
    end
  end
end
```